# how to gather all xlsx files from the working directory, except the ones that are open

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
import re

my_path = os.getcwd()
files = [f for f in listdir(my_path) if isfile(join(my_path, f))]
pattern = re.compile('xlsx$') # xlsx files
pattern_not = re.compile('^~') # the ones that are open start with ~
files = [x for x in files if (pattern.search(x) and (not pattern_not.search(x)))]
```

I wrote this piece of code, which gathers all the files in my working directory, and then filters the `xlsx` files, but **not** the ones that are open.

My question is, is there any way to write this more clean/compact, so without specifying two different `pattern`s, so in my case `pattern` and `pattern_not`

Comment: for opened xlsx files the file name starts with `~$`. So filter only names which don't have `~$` and use them.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa i have also other files in the working directory, for instance `txt`s

Comment: Maybe you can use f.endswith(".xlsx") while searching for files in the list comprehension?

Comment: what about `endswith` and `startswith` instead pattern ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar yeah, thats it, i just figured it out

Comment: @gokhansim f i have a file `test.xlsx`, then if this file is open, the name of the file will be `~$test.xlsx`. so this will not work

Comment: exel/word/pp use `~$` for a tempfile - the rest of the tempfiles name is based on it's original length, it might be somehting like `~$` plus either the full filename or `filename[1:]` or `filename[2:]` (shorter files are used completely, longers get reduced by 1st or 1st/2nd char. You need to find all`~$...` and discard all matching real filenames that possibly would create this tempfile.

Comment: Can't you use this regex: `^\w+\.xlsx` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex solution does not work - you need to get the original file names to exclude them, based on a given lock-file-name. You are only excluding the lockfiles from all xlsx files in your dir.

This could be a first step into the correct direction - carefully review the last problematic one though - you would have to fix that somehow:

```
# exel/word/powerpoint create a lock-file with by prepending ~$ to a filename that you open. 
# the complete lock-file name is different for different lengths of original file lengths.
# Depending on the original name you get 
#   ~$name.xlsx    from   name.xlsx
#   ~$1name.xlsx   from   1name.xlsx
#   ~$12name.xlsx  from   12name.xlsx
#   ~$23name.xlsx  from   123name.xlsx
#   ~$34name.xlsx  from   1234name.xlsx

import re

# file lists all *.xlsx NOT starting with ~$
file = ["test.xlsx", "1test.xlsx", "12test.xlsx", "123test.xlsx", "1234test.xlsx"]
# these are only the lockfiles starting with ~$
lock = ["~$1test.xlsx", "~$12test.xlsx", "~$23test.xlsx", "~$34test.xlsx","~$test.xlsx"]

for lockFile in lock:
    lockBase = lockFile[2:]  # remove the ~$
    nonOpen = [x for x in file if not (x == lockBase or x.endswith(lockBase))]
    isOpen =  [x for x in file if x.endswith(lockBase)]

    print("Locfile:", lockFile)
    print("Is open:", isOpen)
    print("Non open", nonOpen)
```

Output:

```
Locfile: ~$1test.xlsx
Is open: ['1test.xlsx']
Non open ['test.xlsx', '12test.xlsx', '123test.xlsx', '1234test.xlsx']

Locfile: ~$12test.xlsx
Is open: ['12test.xlsx']
Non open ['test.xlsx', '1test.xlsx', '123test.xlsx', '1234test.xlsx']

Locfile: ~$23test.xlsx
Is open: ['123test.xlsx']
Non open ['test.xlsx', '1test.xlsx', '12test.xlsx', '1234test.xlsx']

Locfile: ~$34test.xlsx
Is open: ['1234test.xlsx']
Non open ['test.xlsx', '1test.xlsx', '12test.xlsx', '123test.xlsx']

# problematic - all other files end on this pattern, you would have 
# to smarten the testing quite a bit to avoid this:
Locfile: ~$test.xlsx
Is open: ['test.xlsx', '1test.xlsx', '12test.xlsx', '123test.xlsx', '1234test.xlsx']
Non open []   # all end on test.xlsx - thats a problem ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd substitute your pattern for

```
^[^~]+\.xlsx$
```

And delete your pattern_not. That regex should only match files that don't start with ~ and end with .xlsx (it won't match when a file has ~ midway though)

Comment: Then it matches because it doesn't start with ~ (and doesn't incur in "(it won't match when a file has ~ midway though)")

Comment: if you open `"dada.xlsx"` - Excel creates a lock-file `"~$dada.xlsx"` - you cant match either while `"~$dada.xlsx"` is present - because as long as it is, the `"dada.xlsx"`  is open. If you open `"longerfilenam.xlsx"` the lockfile is called `"~$ngerfilenam.xlsx"` so a simple backref wont work either

Comment: @PatrickArtner are you sure on the fact that the file name gets shortened (for the lock file)? If not, it could be done checking if the files recovered by this regex exist with ~.